# Backbone collection setting default API url using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, api, backbone.js, requirejs

How can I set a default url/server for all my requests from collections and models in Backbone?

Example collection:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    '../models/communityModel'
], function(Backbone, CommunityModel){
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/communities', // localhost/communities should be api.local/communities
        model: CommunityModel,
        initialize: function () {
            // something
        }
    });
});
```

I make an initial AJAX call to get my settings including the url of the API (api.local).

How can I reroute the requests without passing it to all my models or hardcoding the url in the models and collections?

Comment: I think I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30585563/53468

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your url takes a string or a function.

with your settings ajax call you can store it in a proper location,
and go fetch that from the function

to use your example:
suppose your ajax call, saved the url in a `myApp.Settings.DefaultURL`

```
define([
    'backbone',
    '../models/communityModel'
], function(Backbone, CommunityModel){
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function(){
            return myApp.Settings.DefaultURL + '/communities';
        }, 
        model: CommunityModel,
        initialize: function () {
            // something
        }
    });
});
```

**remark**
make sure this url is somehow caught or handled when it would be fired before your settings are set, if your initial ajax call fails or takes its time, your app might already be started without it's settings set, should one use a `model.save()` at that point, you would need to handle this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to avoid a global myApp object (I am using RequireJS as a module loader), so i cannot access it in my collection. Maybe a bad design decision? I thought of something similar to jQuery.ajaxSetup() for Backbone.

Comment: requireJS does not limit you here, you just need to structure your code differently, the idea above is that once the model needs to be saved, it will request the url from somewhere trough that funtion, it can be a global myApp, it can be a config module you define yourself.

Comment: I accept your answer as it is the proper way to set the URL in Backbone. I think my question is more RequireJS related than Backbone. Sadly, I still have no clue how to get my settings from a different module and to store variables in there without using globals or without making an AJAX call again everytime.

Comment: isn't it possible to have a configuration (or app) module in requireJS? you can list that as your dependency module here, just like you do with the communityModel.

Answer (score 0):

By over-riding (but not *over-writing*) the `Backbone.sync` method you can achieve the same result without having to add the same code to every single model/collection.

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'myApp'], function (_, Backbone, myApp) {
    'use strict';

    // Store the original version of Backbone.sync
    var backboneSync = Backbone.sync;

    // Create a new version of Backbone.sync which calls the stored version after a few changes
    Backbone.sync = function (method, model, options) {
        /*
         * Change the `url` property of options to begin with the URL from settings
         * This works because the options object gets sent as the jQuery ajax options, which
         * includes the `url` property
         */
        options.url = myApp.Settings.DefaultURL + _.isFunction(model.url) ? model.url() : model.url;

        // Call the stored original Backbone.sync method with the new url property
        backboneSync(method, model, options);
    };
});
```

Then in your model/collection you can just declare the `url` as usual (e.g. `url: '/events`)

Don't forget to require the file with the new `Backbone.sync` code somewhere.