# Backbone set global api url root for all fetch

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

My API server and My website have 2 different URLs !

E.g :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'infrastructure/session/session'],
    function($, backbone, _,session){
        var Model = backbone.Model.extend({

            urlRoot: "api/user/"+session.userIdConnected+"/biometrics/motion/scores",

            findFromDate:function (startDate) {
                this.fetch({ data: $.param({ from: startDate}) })
            },
            initialize: function(){

            }
        });

        return Model;
    });
```

Backbone fetch on my website url that is normal because I provided a relative api call url to my model.

Is there somewhere I can set a global url root for all my API calls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217938/backbone-collection-setting-default-api-url-using-requirejs) could help you.

```
define([
    'backbone',
    '../models/communityModel'
], function(Backbone, CommunityModel){
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function(){
            return myApp.Settings.DefaultURL + '/communities';
        }, 
        model: CommunityModel,
        initialize: function () {
            // something
        }
    });
});
```

with myApp.Settings.DefaultURL global variable which saves the url(s).