# Global model base url and optional automapping

Tags: rest, backbone.js, model

Is there a way to set a global `api_root` attribute instead of repeating the declaration over and over in the codebase?

So instead of:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/user',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
});
var user = new UserModel();
user.save(userDetails, {
    success: function (user) {
        alert(user.toJSON());
    }
});
```

I could have set an app-wide attribute like:

```
app.api_root = 'https://api.ltmo.com/';
```

And then just map according to convention:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ // maps to https://api.ltmo.com/users/
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
});
var user = new UserModel();
user.save(userDetails, {
    success: function (user) {
        alert(user.toJSON());
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you expect `UserModel` to know its name if you don't tell it? `UserModel` isn't a class in the usual sense, it is just a variable that happens to have a name but the thing it references doesn't know anything about that name.

Comment: I don't know how I'd get around javascript poor instrospection. The question is about convention over configuration.

Comment: In fact: There are two questions:
 1- how to set a global api prefix.
 2- If there is a way to automatically map the model "name" to an URL when it follows a convention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone collection setting default API url using RequireJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217938/backbone-collection-setting-default-api-url-using-requirejs)

Comment: No... Muy stack is Python based.

Answer (score 0):

you could solve this on the jQuery level with [ajaxprefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/):

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
  options.url = 'https://api.ltmo.com/' + options.url;
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this is being down-voted. would love to hear what is wrong with this approach (knowing it might not fit erery use case)